# How to create a text box that can be styled globally?

Tags: framed

I'm writing a thesis and would like to add a box with text at the beginning of each chapter summarising main points. At the moment I'm using `framed` with `itemize` within it, which looks okay and does the job, but I would like to make it look nicer.

At the moment it looks like that: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdBiq.png]
But I would like something like this: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C5Cd.png]

I'm quite new to LaTeX and suspect `framed` may not be the right environment here, but I'm a bit lost. What is the best way to present styled text boxes that can be modified globally?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `mdframed` package is probably what you are looking for. It has lots of customization options, and shadows, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to use the [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newlist{myitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitem,1]{label=\ding{118}}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newmdenv[
shadow=true,
frametitle=This chapter at glance...
]{mynote}

\begin{document}

\begin{mynote}
This chapter:
\begin{myitem}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{myitem}
\end{mynote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package was used to define a customized itemize-like environment with the desired symbol.